# How do you remove the object line between two objects when joined?

Tags: objects, sculpting, sculpt

I've been playing with blender for a little bit, and at the moment I'm having issues on joining two objects together in the sculpt mode. Specifically, I'm trying to get rid of the line between the objects when I joined them. If you need a visual, check out the image below. I outlined the line in black. I want to give it a more organic flow. Let me know if I need to supply anything else. I am using Blender 2.83.3 at the moment. Thanks! ^.^

[image]

Here is an update for my comment to moons. I can't select any other object for the modifier of boolean, because the objects are conjoined from the earlier ctrl + j. :S

[image]

Comment: _Remesh_ , or   _Remesh_ modifier? Or maybe that would screw the surface too much for you. Depends on how hi-res you're working.

Comment: so now that they are one unique object, I guess they are still 2 separate meshes, so use the method I give in my answer, i.e. the Boolean tool (not modifier)

Comment: After some rest, I tried the boolean from the faces panel, but the whole object just disappears, but its not hidden. :S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't sculpt 2 objects at the same time, and even joining the 2 objects won't be enough to create a weld between the 2 as they will still be 2 separate meshes. What you need to do is either keep them 2 separate objects and use the *Boolean* modifier, or join them and use the *Boolean* tool (the one I explain below). In both case make sure that the mode is *Union*

*Boolean* tool: Join the 2 objects (<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>), go in *Edit* mode, select one of the 2 meshes, go in the header menu (or press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>) > *Face > Intersect (Boolean)*, then in the *Operator* box choose *Union*.

Now you can sculpt the way you want.

[image]

Comment: Hiya moon, the last time I reattached these objects were a while ago, so unfortunately ctrl + z 'ing won't really work. Can I still use the boolean intersect even though they are still one object or am I royally out of luck?

Comment: Yes the Intersect tool I'm talking about is for two or more meshes within the same object. But did I guess well when I said that your meshes were separated (within the same object)?

Comment: I'm still massively confused, Since the objects are now categorized as one object, How do I select the other? I'll update the main post with what I mean to clarify. I also tried the boolean union, and it made my object just disappear. :X

Comment: If you have multiple joined objects you can try selecting just one whole by using the keyboard shortcut "L" while in edit mode. Go into edit mode, deselect everything and put your mouse over one of the objects and press L. This should have selected one of the objects, now separate them by using "P"-"Selection".

Comment: Fort Ash, Thank you! This is what I was looking for. The items are now separate from the main object, and I can now use the boolean method that Moon suggested. :)

Answer (score 4):

Another solution: Remesh in Sculpt Mode.
After joining 2 (ctrl+J) you can merge them to one solid (waterproof) mesh by remeshing it like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]